# CSS Box-Shadow Isn't Working With Textarea In Webkit

Tags: css, webkit, textarea

This simple code is not working in Chrome or Safari...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style>
:required {box-shadow:0 0 5px red;}
</style>
<body>
<form>
<textarea required></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It works just fine in Firefox and Opera.  Also, `border:1px solid red` works just fine in webkit browsers.  What's the deal?  I even tried `textarea {display:block;}` thinking that it could have been an inline issue.

Comment: works fine for me using chromes web dev tools + adding `required` to the stackoverflow answer textarea

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

to force the awesome webkit render textarea as an ordinary block and apply all the CSS you write.

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xj5wa/4/)

Comment: I'll give you a useful, as it did work.  I don't think this vendor-specific code is the best option, though.

Comment: The thing is that this vendor-specific code is the cause why your styles aren't applied. Note that non-webkit browsers don't exhibit this problem.

Comment: I'm choosing this as the answer.  The border did solve the specific problem that the question was regarding, but this seems to solve that problem, as well as other problems (`border-radius` for instance).

Answer (score 2):

If you give the textarea a *background* declaration of *none* (or a *background-color* declaration for some reason anything except white) the shadow will work.

```
<style> 
:required { 
     background: none; 
     box-shadow:0 0 5px red;
} 
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
textarea:required {
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
   border: solid 0px transparent; // or border: none;
}​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/PaCkY/) and [**Read this**](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

Answer (score 0):

try selecting the `Textarea` via a class or id instead of the `:required` selector